# Get sender's element type (Button, PictureBox etc..)

Tags: c#, types, void, sender

I am using a void for multiple elements. Such as buttons, labels, pictureboxes....

But i need to modify some of the sender's variables. Such as name, top, left etc... This is my code:

```
private void FareSurukle(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(((TYPE_COMES_HERE)sender).Name);      
}
```

If i edit "TYPE_COMES_HERE" to PictureBox, it works on PictureBox. But it gives error on other elements. Like buttons.

Is it possible to get and modify sender's variables without declaring it's type? Or can i make a type check of sender with if's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to modify some of the sender's properties, such as name, top, left

You don't have to inspect the exact type for that. The controls you mention all inherit from a base class that contains all these properties, aptly named `Control`:

```
MessageBox.Show(((Control)sender).Name);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works exactly like i wanted. I also thinked about this but i didn't know they were called "Control". I tried other things such as "Type, Element"...

Comment: You can [check the inheritance tree on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can try casting to each type and do something with it if not `null`:

```
var button = sender as Button;
if (button != null)
{
    // do something with button
}
var pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
if (pictureBox != null)
{
    // do something with pictureBox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void FareSurukle(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (sender is PictureBox)
     {
         // do something
     }
     else if (sender is Label)
     {
         // do something
     }
     else if (sender is Button)
     {
         // do something
     }
}
```